# How do I get the latest logrotate, which isn't yet in the apt repositories?

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, logrotate

I'm on 20.04, which has `logrotate` 3.14.0. I need a later version which has important bugfixes.

This [page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+package/logrotate) shows that 20.04 has version 3.14.0, and this [page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/hirsute/+package/logrotate) shows that 21.04 has version 3.18.0 (the one I want).

I don't want to upgrade until the next LTS (22.04 I assume).

What are my options for getting the latest logrotate?

- upgrade to one of interim releases
- wait for next LTS
- PPA (none that I can find??)
- compile from source

Is there any other approach I've not considered?

Comment: File bug reports on Launchpad requesting backport of the important bug fixes?

Comment: You can try downloading it from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/logrotate).  You'll get the `.deb` package.  And then do a `dpkg -i` to install it.  If it asks for various dependencies, then decide whether it's something only it needs.  If so, you can go install it.  But if it requires dependencies that might break something else, then I'd stop and consider another option (i.e., compile from source).

Comment: @muru Thanks that's a good idea.

Comment: @Ray That's a good approach, and I wonder why I didn't think of it! If you add that as an answer I'll close. Thanks.

Comment: Sure!  I've added a little more information that includes what I usually do when I encounter this kind of problem.  I hope it helps.  I *think* that `logrotate` ought to be a program that has few dependencies.  I wouldn't dare suggest this to anyone if it was Python 3 or something -- surely that would break many things!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that I have used before is to just download the `.deb` package from a future release.  For `logrotate`, that would be this [link](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/logrotate).  From here, just select the architecture, and then the mirror to download from.

You can install it by using `dpkg -i`.  If you are concerned about doing this, you can extract the contents into a temporary directory and see if anything looks like it might conflict with something else.  For example:  `dpkg-deb --extract <deb file>`.

When you finally decide to install it, if there are dependencies, it will warn you about them.  (Of course, there is a list at the link above, as well.)  If the dependencies are already satisfied, then you're done.  If they are not, then you can decide whether you should manually download those or if you've gone too far and should stop.  A dependency that many other programs rely on will cause you more problems down the road.

Keep in mind that when you upgrade your system, you might want to remove it and put the old version back and let the system upgrade it itself.

I have done the above previously with programs that had very few (usually no) dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments above, here's an updated list:

- upgrade to an interim non-LTS release (which has the new version)
- wait for next LTS
- official PPA (if one exists)
- ask (on launchpad) for it to be backported
- install `.deb` package
- compile from source

That should be applicable for any package, not just logrotate.